# I have a public function still i am not able to call that function using the object?It says the function is not a member of the class

Tags: vb.net

I am using visual studio 2010
I have created a public function in one class.when i try to call the that function using the objects.I am getting an error that the function is not a member of that class.

BusinessLayer :Status.vb

```
    Public Class Status
    Public Function CheckPUServiceLine(ByVal pintScenario As Integer) As Integer   

    Dim objStatusDac As New DataAccess.StatusDac 

    Dim intResult As Integer

    intResult = objStatusDac.CheckPUServiceLine(pintScenario)

    Return intResult
    End Function
    End Class
```

Vb:

```
  Dim objStatusBiz As New Status
  intResultForServiceLineCheck = objStatusBiz.CheckPUServiceLine(1)
```

When i try to call the function CheckPuServiceLine I am getting an error that 
the function CheckPUServiceLine is not a member of Status

Comment: Is `objStatusBiz` declared as an instance of the class?

Comment: yes its declared as instance

Comment: Well of course you did, it's the last code snippet. Stupid me. :p

Comment: What does this mean: `BusinessLayer :Status.vb`?

Comment: Sorry the name of page is Status.aspx.vb

Comment: It could be because of it being a page. It would probably be better to create a separate class instead.

Comment: I have tried with a separate class still im getting it

Comment: If you are using web forms, and your page is called Status.aspx, you should have a file called `Status.aspx.vb` with a class `Status` that extend the `Page` class. So if what you posted it isn't **that** class, then you have declared two classes with the same name, and what vs is saying is that there is no `CheckPUServiceLine ` function in `Status`class **from Status.aspx.vb file**

Comment: Perhaps Status is resolving to a different class. Right-click and go to the definition and make sure it takes you where you expect.

Comment: Could it be a namespace problem?  You're invoking a Status class from a different namespace?

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a Namespace issue. Status is a common enough class name, that I wouldn't be surprised if you are loading the wrong Status class.

Try to be explicit about the Status class, using the namespace for the class library.

```
Dim objStatusBiz As New MyNamespace.Status
```

You can usually find out which Namespace you are using by clicking on the Status class and pressing F12 to go to the definition for the class (or right clicking and choosing to go to definition).